# How to set svn:ignore to "*" literally

Tags: powershell, svn, parameter-expansion, svnignore

i'm trying to set `*` as value for the `svn:ignore` property of a directory.

Simply running `svn propset svn:ignore * .` doesn't work because the `*` expands to anything in the current directory. It literally adds every possible extension of the files in the current dir, like:

```
*.txt
*.log
```

or the command even breaks, if there are non-versioned files in the directory (as they should be, since i'm trying to set `*`).

In the question [SVN: Cannot set svn ignore on a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934054/svn-cannot-set-svn-ignore-on-a-single-file) the problem was exactly this, but, i am **not** using a shell that expands `*`.
Both `cmd.exe` and `pwsh.exe` do not expand anything passed to executables. Even trying with quotes and **quotes inside quotes** doesn't make a difference or simply generates errors:

```
svn ps svn:ignore *         # the behaviour described
svn ps svn:ignore "*" .     # same as *
svn ps svn:ignore "'*'" .   # sets '*', with single quotes
svn ps svn:ignore '"*"' .   # error Explicit target required ('.' interpreted as prop value)
```

Also, invoking via some other means (like `php -r "shell_exec('svn ps svn:ignore * .');"`) yields the **exact** same result.

So it's `svn` itself the one expand things. How do i stop this?

I tried with the `--ignore-keywords`, described in the [svn docs](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html), hoping `*` is considered a "keyword", but the parameter it's not supported by `propset`.

---

How can you do this?
How does TortoiseSVN do it, via its GUI?

Comment: Why do you need to ignore a literal *? Do you really have a file named *? Why?

Comment: So your intent is to ignore _all_ files in the current directory, whatever their extension may be, now and in the future? If `*` results in _verbatim_ `*.txt`, ... for all extensions among the files in the current dir., perhaps `*.*` works (this is just a shot in the dark).

Comment: The box on [this page of the Red Bean Book](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) claims subversion does pattern matching like `fnmatch`. Have you tried escaping with a backslash, i.e. `\*`?

Comment: @Friedrich no i meant to set the literal string `*` as `svn:ignore` property, which means "ignore all files in the current directory"

Comment: @mklement0 _almost_ working in the same way, except for when files have no dot in their name (`dir/somefilewithoutextension` would not be excluded)

Comment: @Friedrich i tried with `svn ps svn:ignore \* .` and `svn ps svn:ignore "\*" .` and it says `svn: E155007: 'C:\$GetCurrent' is not a working copy`, as if it's trying to go over the contents of the root of the current drive (``\`` in windows can be used to reference the root of the drive in which the current working directory resides). - So i tried `svn ps svn:ignore \\* .` (with or without quotes doesn't make a difference as powershell escape char is the backtick `\``, and cmd's is _usually_ a caret `^`), but it sets a literal `\\*` (2 backslash+1 star)

Comment: guys i **kinda** found a solution, ugly but working.. i posted it below. still i'm not satisfied with it as this is more of a challenge than a question at this point (also because, in the meantime i can use TortoiseSVN to set this damn asterisk)

Comment: Glad you found a solution. I would probably have resorted to ignoring the containing directory altogether. Then you would have to create the directory, either through the application or a build system action.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found i dumb way to do it, but i'm starting to think that this might be the *only* way to do it...

```
echo * > star
svn ps svn:ignore --file star .
del star
```

This makes use of a support file containing just a star `*` (and possibly whitespace, but that doesn't make any difference).